# Stop java rx interval observable from queuing items

Tags: rx-java

I have an `Observable.interval` that emits an item every 10 seconds. Inside my subscriber I have a synchronous operation that some times last more than 10 seconds. The result is that my observable emits every 10 seconds so when the synchronous operation ends the subscriber gets called many times in a row.

Here is what I have:

```
Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Long aLong) {
            aSynchronousOperation(); // Last more than 10 seconds
         }
     });
```

What I want to do is maybe "flush" the observable after completing the synchronous operation.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `observeOn` honors backpressure and will buffer emissions from interval, and will emit when subscriber finish its work.
Actually you can theoretically get `MissingBackpressureException` as the default buffer can get overflowed (theoretically because your interval of 10 sec is quite long).
What you want here is to drop items whenever you're still processing, this can be achieved using simple flag, and `filter`, the will prevent any emissions while your work is in progress.

Note that in the case your'e mention, when the work will take more than 10 sec, you'll not get the notification for the `interval` after the work is done, but just after another 10 sec. you can easily change it by implementing different strategy that let the filter pass single value after work is in progress flag raised, and just then block additional emissions.

```
 AtomicBoolean workInProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .filter(aLong -> !workInProgress.get())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(aLong -> {
                workInProgress.set(true);
                aSynchronousOperation();
                workInProgress.set(false);
            });
```

Comment: I tried what you say but it isn't working. The Observable emits all values at once when the work is done. Also, why did you use AtomicBoolean and not a simple boolean?

Comment: the key here is the observeOn, did you use it? I'm using atomic boolean because the subscriber and the subscription operates on different threads, the filter will operate at computation while the subscriber at io.

Comment: I switched the order and put `observeOn` before `filter` making the filter running on io thread too. My bad! Thanks for your answer. It seems it works.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical operator for this case is `onBackPressureDrop`:

```
Observable
.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.onBackPressureDrop()
.subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Long aLong) {
        aSynchronousOperation(); // Last more than 10 seconds
     }
 });
```

Comment: From my understanding (and testing) it will not help here as we have default amount of backpressure buffer, thus drop will act only after this buffer will be filled, meaning in this case we'll not get drop, and we'll get multiple emissions in a row. seems that overriding the default buffer of RxJava cannot be done dynamically. am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's why you want the operator to be as close as possible to the long-running operation.

Comment: how does make it closer helps?

Comment: It doesn't work. From what I gather the problem is that interval is a cold observable, meaning that it emits values lazily. So there is never backpressure to begin with.